# Find and store all innerhtml of div to php variable

Tags: php, innerhtml

I’m trying to store the content of a `div` to a variable.

Example:

```
  <div class="anything">
    <p>We don't know the content of this div</p>
    </div>
```

I want to search for `<div class="anything">` and store everything between opening and the end tag.

We also want to avoid using absolute pathnames, so that it only searches the current HTML/PHP file for this `div` where the code is present.

Is this possible with PHP, or is this only possible with JavaScript ?

Comment: is that `class="anything"` unique to the div?, or in a unique position, e.g. "always the first div in the file"?

Comment: For same page, requires Javascript.

Comment: thanks for the replies ,
@crayon violent: no, we want to capture everything with the given class name .. 
in javascript we got and can use getElementsByClassName('anything').innerhtml
i would like solve this using php so we can store this data to a session or cookie and parse it on another page

Comment: search the whole current file, like you would with preg_match

Comment: okay well there are DOM manipulation classes in php that make grabbing the contents similar to what you'd do in javascript. There's http://www.php.net/DOM or I like this one because it's a lot like jQuery syntax: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ I would suggest you do NOT use regex (e.g. preg_match) for this.

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway?  You already know what's in your DIVs...otherwise, how did you put it there?

Comment: I disagree with the downvote of the question. It's obviously a beginner's question and we all went through this kind of interrogations one day.

Answer (score 3):

### PHP is not that intelligent. He doesn't even know what he says.

PHP is a [server-side language](http://php.about.com/od/phpbasics/a/Php-Is-A-Server-Side-Language.htm). It has absolutely NO clue about what the DOM (ie. what is displayed in your browser's window) is when it delivers a page. Yeah I know, PHP **rendered** the DOM, so how could it not know what's in there?

Simply put, let's say that **PHP doesn't have a memory of what he renders**. He just knows that at one particular moment, he is delivering strings of characters, but that's all. He *kind of* doesn't get the big picture. The big picture goes to the client and is called the DOM. The server (PHP) forgets it immediately as he's rendering it.

Like a red fish.

[image: I'm PHP the red fish]

To do that, you need JavaScript (which is on the client's computer, and therefore has complete access to the rendered DOM), or if you want PHP to do this, you have to retrieve an **full-rendered page** first.

So the only way to do what you want to do in PHP is to get your page printed, and only then you can retrieve it with an http request and parse it with, in your case, a library such as [simpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

### Quick example on how to parse a rendered page with simpleHtmlDom:

Let's say you know that your page will be available at http://mypage.com/mypage.php

```
$html = file_get_html('http://mypage.com/mypage.php');

foreach($html->find('div.anything') as $element) 
    echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably need a combination of those.

In your Javascript:

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("anything")[0].innerHTML();
document.getElementByID('formfield').value(content);
document.getElementByID('hiddenForm').submit();
```

In your HTML/PHP File:

```
<form id="hiddenForm" action="path/to/your/script">
<input type="hidden" name="formfield" value="" />
</form>
```

In the script you defined in the form action:

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $content = $_POST['formfield'];
    // DO something with the content;
}
```

Alternatively you could send the data via AJAX but I guess you are new to this stuff so you should start slowly :)

Cheers!
steve

Comment: Short addition after reading your comment above.
Since you want to do this with multiple div's you just can iterate over all the alements returned by document.getElementsByClassName()

Answer (score -1):

You could use JS to take the .innerHTML from the elements you wan and store them in .value of some input fields of a form and then use a submit button to run the PHP form handling as normal. Use .readOnly to make the input fields uneditle.