# Is there a variable that refers to "this" (the page itself)?

Tags: php

I want to get the equivalent of the `this` variable to refer to the php page object. Is there a way to get that object and query it for functions, variables, etc?

Comment: What do you mean by "page object"? For a PHP class, you can refer to itself by using `$this->method()` or `$this->property`

Comment: PHP is a server-side language - it doesn't care about pages (not to mention it works from CLI as well).

Comment: @reformed I mean, the object that everything is run on for a php page. so not inside a class, but just on the ".php" page inside the tags `<?php ... ?>`.

Comment: ok, so you can try to access the file (by `file_get_contents()`) and parse it to find what's enclosed between the tags. Apart from that... A PHP script is not self-knowing.

Comment: @Jivan that's not actually true. There's a multitude of self-reflecting functions available which can accurately tell you what functions / classes / objects / methods / properties / constants / variables / etc. are defined. Since a PHP script is fully self-containing, it has to know exactly what's inside at any point in time during its execution. Using abovementioned methods, you can manually see what is where exactly.
Nonetheless, the OP seems not to understand the nature of PHP as not having a global object containing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "the PHP page object". If you want to know all defined functions, variables, etc. you can ask PHP using various functions for them. Functions like [get_defined_functions()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php), [get_defined_vars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php), etc.

Comment: _There is no such thing as "the PHP page object"_ - I had **exactly** the same sentence in mind before reading your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you **can't** access the DOM from PHP. And there's a good reason for that.

The quick answer is : PHP is server-side. The long answer is a bit more complicated.

Two days ago I posted an answer on SO about this topic.

[I kindly invite you to have a loot at this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394363/find-and-store-all-innerhtml-of-div-to-php-variable/21394499#21394499)